# How do I solve the de-serialization problem in Java And JPA?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, orm

How do I solve the de-serialization problem in jpa?

I am using Spring Boot, java and JPA and connecting with Postgres.
But the problem is that there are Member, DashBoard, Post, and SubPost entities
When deleting the Post entity, the top entity of the SubGraph, there are cases where even the bottom entity is deleted and sometimes it is not deleted.

The Post entity code is as follows.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Builder
@ToString
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long graphId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "dashboard_id")
    private DashBoard dashboard;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "member_id")
    private Member member;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "graph", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<SubPost> subPost;

}
```

The SubPost entity code is as follows.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@ToString
public class SubPost {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long subgraphId;

    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    Map<String, Object> testCol;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "member_id")
    private Member member;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "dashboard_id")
    private DashBoard dashboard;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
    private Post post;
}
```

The value in the test_col column is
{"key1": "test_value1", "key2": "test_value2"} If this is the JSON format, even if you delete Post, SubPost, a sub-entity, **can be deleted well**.
But
[{"key1": "test_value1", "key2": "test_value2"}] If [] is outside in this way, deleting the Post will **not delete the subentity SubGraph**.

Then the following error occurs.

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)
at [Source: (String)"[{"key1": "test_value1", "key2": "test_value2"}]"; line: 1, column: 1]

I think it's a good way to solve the problem by annotation or type change, is there such a way?
What is the cause and solution of this error?

The code in the SubGraph

```
@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
@Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
Map<String, Object> testCol;
```

I changed it like this.

```
@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
@Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
LinkedHashMap<String, Object> testCol;
```

But the results are the same

Comment: A JSONObject can be deserialized as an Object, but a JSONArray can not be deserialized as an Object.  This as such has got nothing to do with JPA or Postgres.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
If you can't deserialize JSONArray to Object
Is this the problem because there is an object in the value here?

@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
@Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
Map<String, Object> testCol;

Comment: Sorry based upon your question, I can not figure what your original JSON is, and how you are calling this code.  I am guessing that there is a one-to-many relation ship between POST and SUBPOST.  I have no idea what the use of testCol is.  Linkage should be through SUBPOST:id no?